# server preload with cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

We are serving our angular 6 bassed website through cloudfront CDN. We have checked HTTP2 in cloudfront setting. How do we use HTTP2 server push (preload) feature to boost performance of website like in cloudflare.

In cloudflare one can pass LINK header in request like Link: ; rel=preload; as=script

Comment: CloudFront doesn't support HTTP2 server push yet.

Answer (score 6):

As of this writing, CloudFront supports HTTP/2 but does not implement [server push based on `Link: ... rel=preload`](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218367338-HTTP-2-Server-Push) response header sniffing, as Cloudflare does.